# How to check if one list is equal to another list created using a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

```
from math import pi

class Circle(object):
    'Circle(x,y,r)'

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, r=1):
        self._r = r
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Circle({},{},{})'.\
               format(self.getx(), self.gety(),\
                      self.getr())

    #silly, but has a point: str can be different from repr
    def __str__(self):
        return 'hello world'

    def __contains__(self, item):
        'point in circle'

        px, py = item
        return (self.getx() - px)**2 + \
               (self.gety() - py)**2 < self.getr()**2

    def getr(self):
        'radius'

        return self._r

    def getx(self):
        'x'
        self._lst.append(self._x)
        return self._x


    def gety(self):
        'y'
        self._lst.append(self._y)
        return self._y

    def setr(self,r):
        'set r'
        self._r = r

    def setx(self,x):
        'set x'
        self._x = x

    def sety(self,y):
        'set y'
        self._y = y
    def move(self,x,y):
        self._x += x
        self._y += y
    def concentric(self, d):
        d = self._list
    def area(self):
        'area of circle'

        return (self.getr())**2*pi

    def circumference(self):
        'circumference of circle'
        return 2*self.getr()*pi
```

My question is worded kinda awkwardly but what I am trying to do is check if 2 different circles have the same center `(x,y)`. I think the easiest way to solve this would be to input the 2 points into a list but I am not sure how to compare the 2 lists as every time i try my code it adds everything to the same list

Comment: Wait, are you trying to check if two instances of a classes have the same variables basically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following method to your `Circle` class.

```
def equal_center(self, other):
    'check if another circle has same center'
    return (self._x == other._x) & (self._y == other._y)
```

**Usage**

```
C1 = Circle(3, 5, 8)
C2 = Circle(3, 5, 10)
C3 = Circle(3, 2, 1)

C1.equal_center(C2)  # True
C1.equal_center(C3)  # False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help works perfectly idk why i didnt think to do it that way originally

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a function which takes two circle objects and returns if the coordinates are the same or not by comparing the `x` and `y` values of each object:

```
def same_center(circle_1, circle_2):
  if circle_1.getx() == circle_2.getx() and circle_1.gety() == circle_2.gety():
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

This solution is much easier than using lists and should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two instances of the class...

```
a = Circle(0,0,1)
b = Circle(0,0,1)
```

You could add them to a list of circles...

```
circles = [a,b]
```

And loop through the list, checking their values...

```
for i in circles:
    for j in filter(lambda x  : x != i, circles):
        if i._x == j._x and i._y == j._y:
            return True #two circles have same center
```

This should work for n instances of the class, though if its only two you want to check

```
if a._x == b._x and a._y == a._y:
   return True
```